# Suspicious diagrams depicting PGT of D flip flop

Tags: flipflop

I encountered a designing problem in digital system:

Add the necessary logic circuitry to accommodate the
transfer of data from memory into the A register.The data values from
memory are to enter the A register through its D inputs on the PGT of
the first TRANSFER pulse; the data from the sum outputs of the full adders
will be loaded into A on the PGT of the second TRANSFER. In other
words, a LOAD pulse followed by two TRANSFER pulses is required
to perform the complete sequence of loading the B register from
memory, loading the A register from memory, and then transferring
their sum into the A register.

When I tried reading the solution, the text introduced a D flip flop, which I thought it depicted falsely regarding the active transition (which is PGT, not NGT)

[image]

Is the book's solution right? Or does it need correcting?

Answer (score 1):

You can see that on the book's D flip flop, there's a ring before the \$CLK\$ input.

That denotes an inversion, and can be though of as a short way of writing an inverter. That notation can be found for example in a NAND gate. In fact, the inverter symbol iterself can be thought of as a buffer followed by an "inversion ring".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkgNxI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can then understand that the \$!TRANSFER\$ signal leading edge is the \$TRANSFER\$'s signal falling edge.

Comment: This may also be encountered defined as "bubble" notation. Then one of the steps might be "pushing bubbles through" the logic to simplify the circuit diagram.